# Visual studio 2012 express. Generate create database sql script like in PHP myAdmin

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I have a sql database opened in Visual Studio 2012 express database explorer and would like to generate create table sql script for the entire database.

In PHP myAdmin there is such a functions but can't find it in VS 2012 express. If you open table for table the create table script is displayed and can be copied one by one but there seem to be no such function when selecting multiple tables or whole database.

Does anyone know if it's possible in VS 2012 Express?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SQL Server Management Studio Express.

Comment: Looks good, to bad something seems broken there. Downloaded it twice and install keeps failing with a long error code. Closed the virus scanner and all other programs but keeps failing suggesting I should try downloading it again. The 32 bit version won't install because I have 64bit win 7 and 64 won't install saying I should download it again. Maybe try again tomorrow

Comment: I see, googling for the sql server management studio express got me on a 2005 edition (top hits) now maybe on the right page: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062